# Dart: find the key from the value and add to a new list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to search certain value and add to List.

```
a = [
   {anna: 2},
   {jane: 9},
   {paul: 1},
]

b = [1, 2],
```

I want to search the name on `list a` from the value of `list b`. So that `list c` becomes,

```
[paul, anna]
```

I successfully loop the `list b`. But, I could not look for the value and return the key to add to the `list c`.

```
List.generate(
        b.length, (index) {
      <----- stuck ----->
    });
```

I know I can use .addAll to add to the `list c`. How can I return the key value of `list a`?

Comment: Are you sure you have a List<Map<String,int>> and not just a Map<String,int>?

Comment: It is like that since the data was coming from mongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
var a = [
  {"anna": 2},
  {"jane": 9},
  {"paul": 1},
];

var b = [1, 2];

List c = [];
for (var item in a) if(b.contains(item.values.first)) c.add(item.keys.first);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution:

```
var names = a.where((e) => b.contains(e.values.first)).map<String>((e) => e.keys.first).toList();
```